# PDF reader, aside from Acrobat's, that supports 3D images

Tags: pdf-reader

I have some PDFs with 3D images that I need to use.  They show up on Adobe Acrobat Reader nicely, but I'd like to have another reader that will handle them.  So far, I've tried Foxit, Evince, and Sumatra.  All three have a blank window where the 3D image shows up on Adobe Reader.

Ideally, I'd like one for Microsoft Windows that doesn't cost anything, at least for evaluation, but I can do some testing on Mac OSX and Linux, so readers for them would work; also, I'm willing to pay some money to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[Nuance - PDF Reader](http://www.nuance.com/products/pdf-reader/index.htm)

Looks like a wealth of features are offered including multi-layer graphics. It does not explicitly call out 3D; however the mention of viewing SL within a PDF sounded interesting so perhaps it may suffice.

Best of all it is free.

Comment: It doesn't do 3D graphics.